# My ViewModel injection has stopped working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, koin, koin-scope

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:641)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978) 
     Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: |- No definition found for class:'com.nav.noteit.viewmodel.NoteViewModel'. Check your definitions!
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.throwDefinitionNotFound(Scope.kt:287)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:257)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:224)
        at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:205)
 at com.nav.noteit.fragments.FragNotes$special$$inlined$inject$default$1.invoke(ComponentCallbackExt.kt:61)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at com.nav.noteit.fragments.FragNotes.getNoteViewModel(FragNotes.kt:48)
        at com.nav.noteit.fragments.FragNotes.initViewModel(FragNotes.kt:74)
        at com.nav.noteit.fragments.FragNotes.setUpFrag(FragNotes.kt:56)
        at com.nav.noteit.fragments.FragBase.onViewCreated(FragBase.kt:50)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3019)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:551)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1701)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:262)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:478)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1525)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8068)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

Initially it was working completly fine suddenly it is showing me this error. even after I provide all the references in module.
This is my app module.

```
        Room.databaseBuilder(get(),NoteDatabase::class.java,"note_database").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
    }

    single  {
        NoteRepo(get())
    }
    viewModel {
        NoteViewModel(get())
        SearchViewModel()
    }
```

This is how I inject and use my ViewModel.

```
      noteViewModel.allNotes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
                it?.let {
                    adapterNotes.updateList(it)
                }
            }
```

I tried removing all the changes before it was working even after removing all the changes it is still showing me this error. Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: Have you done what it says i.e. ***No definition found for class:'com.nav.noteit.viewmodel.NoteViewModel'. Check your definitions!***

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes I did all the things it says